# vb.net DataTable Select Where Statement throws error (DBNull Value)

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I want to retrieve the number of occurences (get count) in Column "PreparedBy" where the value is not empty ("").

To do so I build a Select Where Statement but it throws an error, because the datatable column can contain a string of nothing ("") or a string not equal to ("").
But on initialization the column is empty (DBNull.Value), so it is empty but not ("").

I tried to solve it with an inner if (IIF) but as soon as I try ask something else than "ISDBNULL" it throws the error.

```
Dim iCountPrepared As Integer = dtLeft.Select().Where(Function(s) CType(s("Type"), String) = "Dep" And Not CType(IIf(IsDBNull(s("PreparedBy")), "", CType(s("PreparedBy"), String)), String) = "").Count()
```

It is not enough to check whether the field is DBNull.Value, it is important to check whether the value is not empty ("").

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Would seem cleaner to me to use something like `IsDBNull(s("PreparedBy") OR String.IsNullOrEmpty(s("PreparedBy"))` You might even have more sucess with something like `s("PreparedBy") = DbNull.Value`

Comment: somehow I can't use this approach in combination with my .count() at the end of the select where statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DataRow` class has its own `IsNull` method to check for database NULLs, i.e. `DBNull.Value`, so you should be using that. This will give you the count of rows that are not NULL or `Nothing` in a particular column:

```vb
Dim count = table.AsEnumerable().Count(Function(dr) Not dr.IsNull("Column1") AndAlso
                                                    dr.Field(Of String)("Column1") <> String.Empty)
```

It's also worth noting that the `DBNull.ToString` method returns an empty string, so you could do this:

```vb
Dim count = table.AsEnumerable().Count(Function(dr) dr("Column1").ToString() <> String.Empty)
```

Comment: Both your solutions work like a charm. Thank you very much - I learned something new today.